# redirect to a url that contains regular expression with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i want to redirect all of requests to a address that contains a regular expreession.

example

```
i.png to ../../templates/default-(something)/i.png
```

this is my Rewite Rule, but it not work.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) ../../templates/default-(.*)/image/$1
```

thank you.

Comment: What's the 'something' and how do you get it? It's not working because it's capturing `i.png` and actually redirecting to literally `... (.*)...`

Comment: the template folder have some folders that name of one of them begins with "default-".

Answer (score 0):

Again, not really sure what you're trying to do, but perhaps it's a folder?

If your structure was `http://......./xxxx/something/i.png`

```
RewriteRule ^.*?/(.*?)/(.*?\.png)$ ../../templates/default-$1/image/$2
```

Would get you `http://..../templates/default-something/image/i.png`\

**OR** if you just want to redirect it to something you define:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../../templates/default-something/image/$1
```

Comment: no. 'something' is unknown! ok? it can be everthing. also url is just like i.png.

Comment: You can't redirect with a regular expression to something unknown - you either have to write it out or capture it from somewhere. OR, see my update.